# Prove $\{T_1,\ldots, T_r \}$ is a basis for $V^*$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $\Bbb F$, and let $\alpha=\{v_1,\ldots , v_r\}$ be a basis for $V$ . For each $1 ≤ i ≤ r$, define $T_i:V\to\Bbb F$ by
$T_i(a_1v_1+\cdots+ a_rv_r) = a_i$.
Prove that $\{T_1,\ldots, T_r \}$ is a basis for $V^*$, where $V^*$ is the set of all linear functions $T: V\to\Bbb F$.

I get how to show all the $T_i$'s are linearly independent, but how can I show they span $V^*$?

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that this is only true for finite-dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: @Neal I think that goes without saying given that $V$ has a basis of length $r$...

Comment: @galois Of course. I meant to highlight that implicit assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take any vector $v \in V$. Then it can be written $$v = \sum_{i=1}^{r} a_i\ v_i$$ For some $a_1,...,a_r \in F$. Now let $T \in V^*$ be any *linear* function , then

$$T(v)= T(\sum_{i=1}^{r} a_i\ v_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{r} a_i\ T(v_i)$$

Now as $T(v_i) \in F$ and $a_i = T_i(v), \forall\ \ i\in \lbrace 1,...,r\rbrace$ then we may write

$$T(v) = \sum_{i=1}^{r}c_i\  T_i(v)$$

where $c_i = T(v_i)$. As we have taken $v$ arbitrary then $\lbrace T_1,...,T_r\rbrace$ spans $V^*$.

You have showed that they are L.I. Then it's done.